# Los cookies no se almacenan en el navegador

Tags: php, cookies, response, setcookie

Buen dia,

Estoy trabajando con cookies por primera vez, la logica es la siguente.

El front hace un request de una consulta al middleware y el middleware valida setea el cookie y responde en un cuerpo, el detalle es que los cookies no se almacenan en el browse, si inpecciono la respuesta si me regresa los cookies.

Creo que es un tema de donde los guardo. me podrían auxiliar.

```
                $nameCokie = "uno";
                $valueCookie = "MUCHOVALOR";
                $live =  10*60;
                $path = '/';
                $domain = 'om.com.mx';
                $http = TRUE;
                $onlyHTTP = TRUE;
                setcookie($nameCokie,$valueCookie,$live,$path,$domain,$http,$onlyHTTP);
```

Este seria el response

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]